# Embed Html `alert()` inside C# method call to display alert window MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to add Html code inside a `@functions {}` codeblock where if it matches some condition it will alert the user.

this is what I have so far, and I am getting the error `CS0103: The name 'alert' does not exist in the current context`

this is the code piece that is throwing the error.

```
@functions{

    void doSomething(){

        if(ViewBag.token != null){
                    @alert("@ViewBag.token");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to embed alert() inside a C# code-block within .cshtml

this is the entire code which this function is in

```
@using System.Web.Mvc
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using System
@using System.Web.UI
@model Dependency_Injection_MEF_MVC.Models.Payment

@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh');
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var $form = $('#payment-form');
            $form.submit(function (event) {
                // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks:
                $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', true);

                // Request a token from Stripe:
                Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

                // Prevent the form from being submitted:
                return false;
            });
        });

        function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
            // Grab the form:
            var $form = $('#payment-form');

            if (response.error) { // Problem!

                // Show the errors on the form:
                $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
                $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', false); // Re-enable submission

            } else { // Token was created!

                // Get the token ID:
                var token = response.id;

                ViewBag.token = token;

                // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server:
                $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="Token">').val(token));

                // Submit the form:
                $form.get(0).submit();

            }
        };
    </script>
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-column">
        <div class="form-container">
            <form asp-controller="home" asp-action="processpayment" method="POST" id="payment-form">
                <span class="payment-errors"></span>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <h3>Membership Amount: USD XX</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cardNumber">Card Number</label>
                    <input class="form-control form-input" id="cardNumber" type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number" style= "width:250px;height:25px;font-size:120%">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Expiration (MM/YY)</label>
                    <div>
                        <input class="form-control form-input date-input" type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_month" style= "width:250px;height:25px;font-size:120%">
                        <input class="form-control form-input date-input" type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_year" style= "width:250px;height:25px;font-size:120%">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cvc">CVC</label>
                    <input class="form-control form-input" id="cvc" type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc" style= "width:250px;height:25px;font-size:120%">
                </div>

                <input class="btn btn-default" onclick="doSomething()" id="submit" value="Submit Payment">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@functions{

    void doSomething(){

        if(ViewBag.token != null){
                    alert("@ViewBag.token");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are intended to be completely server-side.  But that script can be easily embeddable; if you move that to the page where you  want it called, just do:

```
@if(ViewBag.token != null){
  <script>
     alert("@ViewBag.token");
  </script>
}
```

And this will get rendered if the token exists.  Functions aren't needed for this; this could be inside of a @helper though.

Comment: I want to do it as a function as i want the alert window to show after `on-click` event, is there a way to embed an alert that will show ViewBag elements something like `<input class="btn btn-default" onclick="@alert(@ViewBag.token)" id="submit" value="Submit Payment">` can this be achievable?

Comment: Yes it would work.  If the button is a submit button, the dialog will appear and then the page will immediately postback.